# Ecto.build_assoc don't associate the records

Tags: elixir

I have a simple user / phones app, where each user has many phone.

The models are defined as follows:

**user.ex**

```
defmodule UserManager.User do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    has_many :phones, UserManager.Phone
  end

end
```

**phone.ex**

```
defmodule UserManager.Phone do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "phones" do
    field :phone_number, :string
    field :phone_status, :string, default: "open"
    belongs_to :user, UserManager.User
  end

end
```

MIGRATIONS

**create_users.ex**

```
defmodule UserManager.Repo.Migrations.CreateUser do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :email, :string
    end
  end
end
```

**create_phone.ex**

```
defmodule UserManager.Repo.Migrations.CreatePhone do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:phones) do
      add :phone_number, :string
      add :phone_status, :string
    end
  end
end
```

**phone_belongs_to_user.ex**

```
defmodule UserManager.Repo.Migrations.PhoneBelongsToUser do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    alter table(:phones) do
      add :user_id, references(:users)
    end

  end
end
```

On iex run the code as follow:

```
alias UserManager.{Repo, User, Phone}
user = %User{email: "john@mail.com"}
Repo.insert!(user)
```

until now is all running well... but when I run `Ecto.build_assoc` elixir don't associate the phone to the user. **Why?** --ps: the code are not throwing any exception--

```
phone = Ecto.build_assoc(user, :phones, %{ phone_number: "052-8888"})
```

Comment: What is `line`? When do you call `build_assoc/3`? Have you checked [examples](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html?#build_assoc/3-examples)?

Comment: "line" was a mistake, it should have written "user". I already edited the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What was missing was to get the user with `user = Repo.get(User, 1)` after having done `Repo.insert!(user)`. And only then do `Ecto.build_assoc`.

Comment: I doubt making a superfluous call to the DB is a good approach. `%User{email: "john@mail.com"} |> build_assoc(:phones, phone_number: "052-8888") |> Repo.insert!()` should be good enough.